# Button Behaviors Expression blend 3

Tags: expression-blend, expression-blend-3, silverlight-embedded

I am using Expression Blend 3 and the Silverlight for Windows Embedded Application project type. What i want to do is have a button where when it is clicked, it will bring a popup box with other buttons to select. Sort of buttons embedded in a button.

The application project type i am using contains no behaviors for some reason so it seems i am fairly limited in the tools available. Is there a way i can achieve this?

Also...I have searched everywhere with zero success, but how can i create a transparent or empty button box color. By default, the button is created with a silver/gray filling, but i want it to be empty so it takes the color of whatever the main page background is. (I am also unable to change the color of the button).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first part, sounds like a ContextMenu or something we can make pretty quick/easy. The second part is also pretty quick/easy and will just require pulling out the Button Style template and customizing it to your needs. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I managed to edit the button through button style template as you suggested, but i am not sure how to go about doing the contextmenu.

Comment: Are you using [Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269476.aspx) in yours? If there isn't a ContextMenu or similar available in the sdk for SL embedded, we can make you one real quick and simple.

Comment: There are no behaviors available in the Assests tab for my project type. I either need to import them or they are unavailable for my project type which is Silverlight for Windows Embedded Application.

Comment: According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592912.aspx) you have Triggers, which is all you'd need if you have DataTrigger, if you have Triggers available I can show you how to whip up what you want real quick.

Comment: If by triggers you are referring to the Events tab where you can assign events to control types, then yes, i have triggers(events) available.

Comment: Ok any solution I can give you is going to require your digging into some actual XAML instead of trying to use the GUI like your events tab. You cool with that? It would help if I knew you had access to DataTrigger and stuff though as opposed to just what you see available in a tab or whatever.

Comment: How can i tell if i have access to DataTrigger? Im new to expression blend/xaml development so im still learning alot.

Comment: Do you know if you have the interactivity/interactions assemblies installed?

Comment: I do not have it interactivity/interactions assemblies installed.